# ace:dataTable to select multiple rows via the shift key in ICEFACES

Tags: javascript, jsf, icefaces

I am working on icefaces ACE Components and currently i am using ace:datatable.
i am using below code

```
 <ace:dataTable var="invoice"  value="#{applicationBean.invoices}"          
      id="dataTableId" rows="10" paginator="true" height="350" paginatorPosition="bottom" page="1" 
selectionMode="multiple" emptyMessage="There are no search results"
 pageCount="4" currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} out of {totalRecords}"
```

i am able to see the data on my table. my problem is suppose there are 10 rows on table and if i select 2nd and pressed shift key and i select 5th rows then it should select 2 to 5 rows ....but its not working in my case. Is there any table attribute do i need to add or any other alternative component or any javascript i need to write for this please suggest me..

Thanks,

Comment: no need of extra javascript code for doing multiple select.

Answer (score 0):

No need of extra javascript code for doing multiple select.
As per the example in Iceface showcase page it is possible to do multiple selection using shift key.

```
<ace:dataTable id="instantCarTableMultiRow"
                      value="#{dataTableSelector.carsData}"
                      var="car"
                      rows="7"
                      stateMap="#{dataTableSelector.stateMap}"
                      selectionMode="multiple"
 >
```

shift is not working may because of pagination or version mismatch.

http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=dataTableBean